# Gatsby: Query and group files based on folder

Tags: javascript, graphql, markdown, gatsby

Is there a way to group files based on their parent folder / subdirectory of root?

File structure:

```
.
├── category-a
│   ├── file-1.md
│   └── file-2.md
└── category-b
    └── file-3.md
```

The only workaround I would find is either add a specific `tag` / `category` to each file (frontmatter) and do the mapping on the client or use multiple queries using filter based in `fileAbsolutePath`

In the end I would like to get the following output:

```
{
  categories: [
    category-a: [ file-1, file-2 ],
    category-b: [ file-3 ]
  ]
}
```